# int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString()) not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net

My int chooseID is not showing anything.

Here is my code:

```
int chooseID = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("e.CommandArgument.ToString()", e.CommandArgument.ToString());
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("chooseID", chooseID);
```

And here's the output:

```
4: e.CommandArgument.ToString()
chooseID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using [`Debug.WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline?view=netframework-4.8) in the way it's intended. You're using the `WriteLine(string, object[])` overload, but the intention is that the first argument is a *format string* which contains placeholders, that are then replaced by the remaining arguments.

So you'd want something like:

```
Debug.WriteLine("e.CommandArgument: {0}", e.CommandArgument);
Debug.WriteLine("chooseID: {0}", chooseID);
```

Or you could just use string interpolation:

```
Debug.WriteLine($"e.CommandArgument: {e.CommandArgument}");
Debug.WriteLine($"chooseID: {chooseID}");
```